# 'File not found' when added to Bridging-Header

Tags: ios, swift, bridging-header

I have a working project, part ObjC and part Swift 3.

I wanted to use ObjC file in my Swift file, so I added `#import "APIHTTPClient.h"` to my bridging file.
[image]
All of a sudden, I got an error message, saying that a inherited file is not found:
[image]
The inherited file is from pod `AFNetworking`.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Add `#import AFNetworking.h` file in the bridging header instead of `#import AFHTTPClient`.

Because `AFNetworking.h` header file importing all the necessary files.